# For given X value, return Y probability on CDF curve

Tags: google-sheets, statistics

I have a CDF curve as shown here in my Google Sheets document:

[image: CDF curve image]

What I would like to do is be able to say: "There is a a% probability of at least €b in revenue". Even using a plain old ruler I can see that there is a ~83% probability of at least €6000 in revenue, however, I seem unable to get the exact figure dynamically in a cell for any given €b.

The closest thing to a solution I came across so far is to use the following, which I figured would mimic the current CDF curve as a normal distribution.

=1-NORMDIST(6000,AVERAGE(F6:F31),stdev(F6:F31),TRUE)

However, this seems to returns far lower numbers than I can read from the chart (0.664507462 is returned for the function above) so the normdist probably doesn't describe the CDF curve accurately.

I also found some solutions using Excel plugins or using MATLAB, but neither of those apply because I'm using Google Sheets.

Anyone who knows a proper solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks! Removed the [Excel]. Cross Validated might help (will post there tomorrow), but I need a Google Sheets specific solution, as mentioned, I already had solutions if the problem was in Excel or MATLAB.

Comment: The Excel solution is in a plugin, of which I can't access the source code. Otherwise I had could have just rewritten to JS and add as GAS code. Unfortunately, as you guessed, that isn't an option either.

Comment: Two questions: Is the CDF based on a cumulative distribution function or is it based on measurements? Can you share a sample spreadsheet so we can avoid copying all those numbers please?

Comment: Q1: Not sure to be honest. They come from a Monte Carlo simulation, which was then -> histogram -> CDF. Q2: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ikQWhcQqFp8dZKohWoAGz4OE_ll0Sb88PzKiQQ_RdhM/edit?usp=sharing). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are running your prediction on the overview which you are not weighting by bucket size.
The plot below shows this issue, at $6000 the normal distribution(red) has a lower probability than the data (black).
[image: Wrong CDF]

You can calculate the overall mean like this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D6:D31, F6:F31) / SUM(D6:D31)
```

And the overall standard deviation like this

```
=SQRT(SUMPRODUCT((F6:F31 - F36)^2, D6:D31) / (SUM(D6:D31) - 1))
```

Where F36 is the calculated mean above.

If you now plug those two parameters into your formula in place of the mean and standard deviation of the overview you get an estimate (green line) of 79% which follows your actually measured cumulative distribution very closely.

[image: Fixed CDF]

Answer (score 1):

Since the CDF is a relatively smooth function, you could use linear interpolation to approximate unknown percentages for given revenue values based on the bracketing known percentages.  For your 6000 example:

```
6000    - 5701.57   p  - 85
----------------- = ------- => p = 82.7416 (approximately)
6890.85 - 5701.57   76 - 85
```

If linear interpolation is not accurate enough for your needs, higher order polynomials interpolation could be attempted.